# Decode function in oracle for null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a java code in which i am comparing the user input values with database values.
I am writing the code to display the alert message to the users on selection of particular division from drop down menu. But there are some alert message which I want to display to all users of every division.
I have the table columns as `sr_n0`, `alert_desc`, `div_code`, `alert_flag`.

Initially I am checking the `div_code = 'division code'` and `alert_flag = 'y'` to display division specific alert message. 
But now I want to know how the `decode` function will work if `div_code = null` and `alert_flag = 'y'`.

I have tried this SQL query :

```
    SELECT  DECODE(DIV_CODE,'61','Division A',
                    '62','Division B', 
                      'ALL')
    FROM ALERTS WHERE ALERT_FLAG='Y';
```

Comment: have you tried it to see what happens? i was assume it would return ALL

Comment: Its returning both ALL and 61.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no match, then the result will be `'ALL'`.  I would strongly encourage you to use the ANSI-standard `CASE` statement, instead of the Oracle-specific `DECODE()` function:

```
SELECT (CASE DIV_CODE
            WHEN '61' THEN 'Division A'
            WHEN '62' THEN 'Division B' 
            ELSE 'ALL'
        END)
FROM ALERTS
WHERE ALERT_FLAG = 'Y';
```

Comment: The code worked for me by using `CASE` statement. Thank You @Gordon

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by writing simple SQL command and it worked for me.

```
SELECT ALERT_DESC FROM ALERTS A 
WHERE 
  A.DIV_CODE IS NULL 
  AND A.ALERT_FLAG='Y' ;
```